# Trapezoid angle X

Tags: geometry

I can't attach the picture here but I'll try to describe it. There is a trapezoid like a carpet as you can see in this picture here: https://www.google.se/search?q=trapezoid&biw=1242&bih=606&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMItcS5k_7SyAIVgahyCh38DQB6#imgrc=WkEqMeLTFqSFBM%3A

The side of the trapezoid that is closest to us is 2A, and all other sides are of side length A. They are asking for the angle in the right hand corner that is furthest away from us so if you imagine that you draw a coordinate system in this carpet where origo is in the middle of the carpet, then they are asking for the angle in quadrant 1. How big is this angle?

Comment: I don't know what angle is asked for. The angles at the bottom two corners are $60$ degrees.  The ones at the top two corners are therefore $120$ degrees.

Comment: The angle that is asked for is the one to the right of the top two corners

Comment: You mean in the sliced off triangle? That's $60$ degrees, in radians $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: No in the trapezoid

Comment: The angle in the top right hand corner of the trapezoid

Comment: I had mentioned that earlier, $120^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the sides of the trapezoid to form a triangle.  You now have two nested triangles, one small one large.  As the bases are parallel the base angles are equal and the triangles are similar.  The smaller base is half the larger so the corresponding other sides of the small triangle are half the sides of the large triangle.  The sides of the trapezoid are therefore half the sides of the large triangle so the sides of the triangle are 2A.  So all three sides are 2A so the triangle is an equilateral one.  So the base angles are 60 degrees.  Then the other to angles of the trapezoid are 120 as they are supplementary to the base angles.

Comment: How do I extend the sides to form a triangle?

Comment: Extend them until they intersect.  They can't be parallel else the two parallel sides of the trapezoid would be equal.

Comment: Please attach a picture, please I'll do anything to understand this question